# clock frequency confusion

Tags: avr, atmega, serial, uart, avr-gcc

I am using an atmega16 micro controller with a 12MHz external crystal oscillator. But I came to know that the internal clock frequency is 1MHz

I need to calculate UBRR value for serial communication. I need a baud rate of 115200.

If I am using 1MHz in UBRR value calculation by using the formula (F_CPU/(16*baud))-1 then I am getting a negative number greater than -1. 
What should be the value of F_CPU?

please do help me as I not an electronics guy.
Thanks in advanced for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default fuse settings for an ATMega are to use the 8MHz internal oscillator (INTOSC) divided by 8 <s>(CLKDIV8)</s>. This means the default clock frequency is 1MHz as you are seeing. *Correction:* for the ATMega16 it seems that there is no CLKDIV8 fuse, it is part of the clock source selection fuse bits - but the default is still 1MHz.

In order to use the external 12MHz clock signal, you need to program the fuse settings to correctly select the clock source and disable division by 8.

"Engbedded" have a really useful free calculator which helps you determine the fuse settings required for AVRs. The calculator can be found [here](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc/). For you it seems something along the lines of `Low:0xE0, High:0xD0` should do, though you will have to check yourself as there are other things like the bootloader reset vector and brown out detection which are set by the fuses.

Answer (score 0):

generally these chips are configurable.  they will boot off of the internal oscillator in case there isnt an external.  then you can keep using that one or software can switch to the external.  then there is usually a clock tree that internal blocks can be switched to use one of the available clocks, THEN once you have selected the clock for your uart, then you do the divisor thing.   certainly you cannot get any baud rate you want with any clock.  1MHz/16 = 62500 so that or half of that would be your fastest, so maybe try 9600 or 4800 if you stick with the 1Mhz.

Comment: For ATMega's, the clock source is selected based on the programmable "fuses" rather than at run time. You can change the clock divider at run time, but not 100% sure you can change the source.

Comment: I was speaking generally...correct from a random atmega doc. The device has the following clock source options, selectable by Flash Fuse bits as shown below. The clock
from the selected source is input to the AVR clock generator, and routed to the appropriate modules.  The device is shipped with internal RC oscillator at 8.0MHz and with the fuse CKDIV8 programmed, resulting in
1.0MHz system clock.

Comment: So configurable but in the case of the atmega specifically it is not runtime it is a flash fuse based setting.  However, you still have to look at the up front divisors and how the clock tree is to each peripheral, some products allow you to pick from available clocks, some dont, some allow a divisor of the selected clock, some dont.  Same answer applies you have to figure out the clock for the uart and go from there.  the best way is to guess and then use a scope (send 0x55 characters for example 8n1 gives a square wave) and adjust based on what you find, often off by a power of two if at all